# Finding the line segments where 2 polygons share an edge

Tags: geometry, godot

I am working on code to place doors between rooms on my levels.  Rooms are lists of points which make up a polygon.  In order to find a place for a door between two rooms, I need to find what line segment(s) are along the edge of both polygons.  Here are some examples, where I would need to identify the highlighted segment(s):

[image: two polygons]

[image: concave polygon]

[image: non-right-angle polygons]

The code which generates the room polygons will always create polygons that don't overlap, but only touch.  How would I go about finding a shared edge like this?  I am using Godot with the built-in scripting language, but the language doesn't matter as much as the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The process goes like this (using python; `is_point_in_polygon` is a conceit, but could be replaced with something like `Polygon.contains` from [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)):

1. Iterate over every point (in both polygons) and check to see if it is inside *both* polygons.  Save these to a list

```
def find_shared_edges(poly_1, poly_2):
    shared_verts = []
    for vert in poly_1+poly_2:
        if is_point_in_polygon(vert, poly_1) and is_point_in_polygon(vert, poly_2):
            shared_verts.append(vert)
```

2. Compare each of these points to each other point.  If the midpoint between two of them is also inside both polygons, then they are a shared edge.

```
    shared_edges = []
    for vert_a in shared_verts:
        for vert_b in shared_verts:
            midpoint = (vert_a + vert_b) / 2

            if is_point_in_polygon(midpoint, poly_1) and \
               is_point_in_polygon(midpoint, poly_2):
                shared_edges.append( (vert_a, vert_b) )
```

3. Eliminate duplicate entries which are the same line segments, just with their endpoints reversed.  This shouldn't be a problem in python if you use `itertools.combinations` instead of the nested for-loops in the above step.

```
    return shared_edges
```

Answer (score 0):

I warn you that you might find a problem with rounding. In particular in diagonals such as in your last example, the segments might not match, or at least appear to not match in a strict check due to the positions of the vertex being truncated to whatever resolution the number data type supports. Hopefully you have a minimum size (i.e. a pixel) such that anything closer than that is considered in the same place. Or at least we have some idea of how big the polygons are.

---

Warning aside, the way you are going to deal with this follows…

First you need candidate segment pairs. If you know what polygons are contiguous, you can consider all of their segments to be candidates for a match. If you do not know which polygons are contiguous, you want to have some idea of where they are, so you only consider those that are nearby.

Once you have a candidate segment pair, collide their bounding boxes (AABB). If no collision, they do not match.

If they collide, it means they are close, however they might still not match.

In this case project the vertex of one segment on the other (it does not matter which one). Compute the distance from the vertex to its projection. If the distance, for both vertex of a segment to their projection on the other segment, is zero (within rounding error), it means they are on top of each other. That is, they match.

Yo can use the collision bounding box will correspond to the part of the segment that is common to both polygons.

---

You say your code generate polygons with this property. Is there any chance you can modify the code to output how they are linked? Perhaps generate a supplementary structure where you can query how the polygons are related.

Comment: Think it would be worth adding here a check of the segments' normals, so you can skip segments that are definitely not parallel? Also: I think the vertex you choose does matter, as you can run into situations where 2 of the 4 vertices don't touch the other segment, but the other 2 do. So you need to check 3 of the 4 if you don't have a heuristic to let you jump to the best candidates.

Comment: @DMGregory we could check for parallels, that could be a good idea. Edit: Thinking about it, I won't advice to rely on it, because rounding.  It does not matter which segment you chose to project on the other segment to check distance. That is distance of the vertex of one segment to the line of the other segment.

Comment: I am not sure I 100% understand your solution, but would it be able to tell exactly *where* the line segments overlap in every case, such as in the last example, where there are no shared vertices between the polygons?  If I am projecting the segment from the bottom polygon onto the segment from the top polygon, how will I know where along the line they share an edge?

Comment: @lsma Two of the corners of the collision bounding box will be the vertices of the segment. See which match the vertices of the segments. It is those two.